# Newbie needs help incorporating recurring tasks into MS Access database

Tags: ms-access, task, recurring

I am a complete novice to programming and the little I know is self taught from 10 years ago.  I have created/am creating a database to track productivity for my team at my new job. I have based it around the "task manager" template within MS access.  The major functionality that I require is to be able to enter in tasks which are recurring at varied intervals. Ideally, I would like the future dates for tasks to self populate the 'tasks' table in advance, or even better, as an a team member enters in the completion info for their current task, to have the next entry then entered into the table.  When  team member pulls up their 'future tasks' or even 'daily tasks', they would see future entries listed automatically and not have to go in and enter each recurring report individually.  Currently, new tasks are entered using a blank version of the 'task details' form and tasks can be edited using a button which brings up the corresponding task on the 'task detail' form, but it edit mode, so completion information can be entered or status changed, but there is no option to make a task recurring and have the information for future dates automatically entered for the team member.

I have downloaded Allen Browne's recur database and its good, but falls short of what I need- or rather - my knowledge  base is falling short on how to incorporate it into what I have built.  There is no 'table' that houses all the recurring events in his db.  He uses a query and I am unsure how to 'connect' it to the task manager form/table.  I have a table in my db called 'tasks' which connects to the 'task manager' form and the 'task details' subform - all part of the template that comes with access.  I have tried to 'connect' everything, but because its query based, its not updating the 'tasks' table and since you cannot have a form based on more than one table/query, I cannot even get the future dates to come up in the 'task management' form or 'task detail' form either. I tried adding the fields from the recur DB to my tasks table, and again- its beyond my abilities - nothing I have tried with my limited knowledge is working.

If anyone can please help me in anyway to figure out a way to connect them both so it all functions- I would be most appreciative!

Thank you,
Debbie

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO which is a code helping forum. You may get better results at, for example, UtterAccess or Experts Exchange.

Comment: Yes, Allen's db uses a Cartesian query to create the recurring task series. If you want to commit those records to a table, then maybe use the query as source for an INSERT SELECT action. Otherwise, create single 'next' record. Whatever the approach, real trick is figuring out what event to put code into. I have used a button click event to 'copy' data from selected record to a new record. Fairly common topic. I agree your question is too broad and this is not the appropriate forum.

Comment: Thank you both for responding. I have tried posting in other forums but usually no one responds. I really do appreciate you both taking the time to answer.

Comment: Do you have a link for other forum posting?